# How does ttk.Entry compare to getpass in terms of safety?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am writing tkinter GUI that requires users to input their passwords. I've heard that getpass module is commonly used to increase the safety of passwords in Python. I have problems with implementing it in my code as it requires the use of terminal. Also, its only apparent advantage is that it does not echo the password in the console, however tkinter doesn't either. I'll use salt and hashes later on but just in comparison which one of the following is safer and why?

```
ttk.Entry(self.settings, show="*")
#...
#vs
import getpass
pwd = getpass.getpass()
#...
```

Comment: I don’t think there’s any safety gain. Either way, you’re storing it in a variable. The safety part is the authentication.

Comment: Is there any other way to make it safe?
I need my users to provide their passwords and then check them against an external database. Ideally I would like to store their credentials in a file so that they wouldn't have to type them every single time they run the application.

Comment: Well if you were going to store them, it would definitely need to be encrypted. I don’t think the entry method makes a deference though.